# Flow Decision Outcome criteria does not evaluate correctly

Tags: visual-workflow, formula, criteria

a collection variable is created to store information in a multi-select picklist field. We are using this collection variable in a decision outcome criteria. It appears that the "Contains" operators is not working as expected. Unable to understand why the conditions are evaluated as false.

DECISION: All Products Selected?
Skipped this outcome because its conditions weren't met: outcome_Yes_ALL_PRODUCTS
Outcome conditions:

1. {!var_Cancelled_Products} ([PHNPro; DBR; Petly Plans; SmartFlow; Cornerstone Support; Other]) Contains PHN
2. {!var_Cancelled_Products} ([PHNPro; DBR; Petly Plans; SmartFlow; Cornerstone Support; Other]) Contains DB
3. {!var_Cancelled_Products} ([PHNPro; DBR; Petly Plans; SmartFlow; Cornerstone Support; Other]) Contains Flow
4. {!var_Cancelled_Products} ([PHNPro; DBR; Petly Plans; SmartFlow; Cornerstone Support; Other]) Contains Petly
5. {!var_Cancelled_Products} ([PHNPro; DBR; Petly Plans; SmartFlow; Cornerstone Support; Other]) Contains Support
6. {!var_Cancelled_Products} ([PHNPro; DBR; Petly Plans; SmartFlow; Cornerstone Support; Other]) Contains Oth
   Logic: All conditions must be true (AND)

Default outcome executed.

[image]

Comment: Can you  edit the post and share the screenshot of the flow element for the same.

Comment: I hope this helps clarify

Comment: Thanks for sharing the screenshot of the decision box and can you also share the screenshot of how you are assigning the multipicklist  value  to the collection variable

Comment: Sai, it seems like when I updated the criteria to a single condition rather than multiple, it worked --> contains PHNPro; DBR; Petly Plans; SmartFlow; Cornerstone Support; Other. I find it strange as ultimately the criteria is evaluating the same. Not clear why it did not work in the first place.

Comment: Does your record contains all the values  because you are using AND condition and if AND condition is expected check if all the Names are exactly matching including Spaces.

Comment: Confirmed that the values being referenced are correctly spelled

Comment: Can you try adding a variable of type multipicklist and add the value there and check the condition?

Comment: When creating such a variable, does the checkbox for "Allow multiple values (collection)" be set to true?

Comment: I hope you want to add a multiselect picklist for a single record in the variable right. If so do not select  allow multiple values option

Comment: the initial variable type that was used was TEXT. Changing it to multi-select picklist we then again see that the default outcome is taken.                                               
DECISION: All Products Selected?
Skipped this outcome because its conditions weren't met: outcome_Yes_ALL_PRODUCTS
Outcome conditions:
{!var_TEST_Canceled_Products} ([PHNPro; DBR; Petly Plans; SmartFlow; Cornerstone Support; Other]) Contains PHNPro; DBR; Petly Plans; SmartFlow; Cornerstone Support; Other
All conditions must be true (AND)

Default outcome executed.

Comment: something seems to be off with the variable. When using the variable in different decision outcomes it is not evaluating it correctly. For example, these products are being selected from a multi-select picklist field "PHNPro; Petly Plans; SmartFlow; Cornerstone Support" and the decision outcome which looks at whether PHNPro is not selected determines that it is true. NOT PHNPro?
Outcome executed: NOT_PHNPro
Outcome conditions:
1. {!var_Cancelled_Products_Multi} ([PHNPro; Petly Plans; SmartFlow; Cornerstone Support]) Contains PHNPro
Logic: Advanced Logic ((NOT (1)))